# group concat between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

Table1: **PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION** :

```
PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID | TITLE
PBID_1                         TITLE_1
PBID_2                         TITLE_2
PBID_3                         TITLE_3
```

Table2: **MAP_ASSOCIATED_PROJECTS**

```
MAP_ID | PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID | ASSOCIATED_PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID 
  1            PBID_1                          PBID_2 
  2            PBID_1                          PBID_3
```

I would like to have a query like for single project_basic_information_id in table 1,give me all of its associated project_basic_information_id(s) and corresponding title(s) in a comma separated value.

Ex:for PBID_1 in table1 I should get output like

```
Project_basic_information_ids  | Project_titles 
pbid2,pbid3                      title2,title3
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.`ASSOCIATED_PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID`) AS PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_IDS,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.`TITLE`) AS TITLE
FROM MAP_ASSOCIATED_PROJECTS a  LEFT OUTER JOIN
`PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION` b ON  b.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID =a.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ASSOCIATED_PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID) AS Project_basic_information_ids  ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.TITLE) AS Project_titles 
FROM MAP_ASSOCIATED_PROJECTS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION b ON a.ASSOCIATED_PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID = b.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID 
WHERE a.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID = 'PBID_1'
GROUP BY a.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID
```

Comment: yep gotcha.Missed that ;( Thanks for the help.It works as expected